# I want to create IF ELSE statement for NULL formitems on Blazor

Tags: c#, if-statement, telerik, blazor

I wanted to create a handler that when the submit button is trigger it should add the record on the database but when the fields are Null or Empty it should throw an error. In my case it always passes. Codes are below:

```
 private async Task OnSubmitHandler(EditContext editContext)
    {
        AssigneeDto assigneeDto = editContext.Model as AssigneeDto;

        if (assigneeDto != null)
        {
            await _assigneeClient.CreateAssignee(sm.id, assigneeDto);
            NotificationReference.Show(new NotificationModel()
            {
                ThemeColor = ThemeColors.Success,
                Text = "Record Added Successfully!",
            });
            FormData = new AssigneeDto();
            CurrentForm = new EditContext(FormData);
            CurrentForm.AddDataAnnotationsValidation();
        }
        else
        {
            NotificationReference.Show(new NotificationModel()
            {
                ThemeColor = ThemeColors.Error,
                Text = "Record Could Not Be Added!",
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: `if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dto.Attribute))`

Comment: Are you are aren't you using a validator? If your question is - How do I validate my `AssigneeDto` object? - then use one of the Data Validation suites available and as Henk suggests the OnValidSubmit handler on `EditForm`.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-validation?view=aspnetcore-6.0 .

Comment: @Fabio Hi Fabio I have tried the above and does not work for me.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis I do not use validators on my DTO maybe if I add validations or create a viewmodel and add the validations there then the IF STATEMENT will work. I will have to try